# JAVA cannot make a static reference to non-static field

Tags: java

this is my first program in JAVA and I'm having problem to understand this error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field *
```

and

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method *

```
public class Cerchio{

   float r;
   float area;
   float cfr;
   final double pi = 3.14;

   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("CIRCLE PROGRAM\n");
      r = 5;
      c_cfr();
      c_area();
      System.out.ptintln("The cir is: " + cfr);
      System.out.println("The area is: " + area);
   }

   float c_cfr(){
      cfr =(float)(2 * pi * r); //casting
      return cfr;
   }

   float c_area(){
      area = (float)(pi * (r*r));
      return area;
   }

}
```

[image: errors]
Can you give me any suggest?
I'm coding on SandIDE on Android

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are calling instance methods and fields from within a static method, something that can't be done because instance fields and methods don't exist without an object, and inside of the main method there is not `this` object. You must instead create an instance of the class, and then call the methods on the instance.

```
public class Cerchio{

  float r;
  float area;
  float cfr;
  final double pi = 3.14;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("CIRCLE PROGRAM\n");

    Cerchio cerchio = new Cerchio();
    cerchio.r = 5;
    cerchio.c_cfr();
    cerchio.c_area();
    System.out.ptintln("The cir is: " + cerchio.cfr);
    System.out.println("The area is: " + cerchio.area);
  }

  float c_cfr(){
    cfr =(float)(2 * pi * r); //casting
    return cfr;
  }

  float c_area(){
    area = (float)(pi * (r*r));
    return area;
  }

}
```

Lots of other problems,...

- You're accessing class fields directly, something that shouldn't be done. Instead, the fields should be private and you should use getters/setters/contructor parameters to get, set and set the fields.
- Your code is unindented making it very hard to read and understand.

Please search this site as this same question has been asked and answered a gabizillion times, and most likely there's an answer out there that is much better than mine. If found, then this question should be closed as a duplicate.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> I didn't understand "Instead, the fields should be private and you should use getters/setters/contructor parameters to get, set and set the fields." I should write private float c_cfr() ?

Your fields are:

```
float r;
float area;
float cfr;
```

This is really not a field but a constant:
    final double pi = 3.14;

and can be replaced / improved by simply using Math.PI.

Your fields should be changed to:

```
private float r;
private float area;
private float cfr;
```

and you should only access them via public getter and setter methods, and only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Ok, so I need to create the object in the class where I have to use the proprieties and methods declarated in the class, right?

Comment: @AlessioMTX: see edit to answer. You must create a variable of Cerchio type inside of the main method and assign it a new Cerchio object, and then you may call methods off of this variable. This should all be well explained in the chapters of your textbook on object creation. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok thank you, it was a stupid error, but I need an explanation like your. I fixed the code so now is easy to read, although isn't right.

Comment: I didn't understand "Instead, the fields should be private and you should use getters/setters/contructor parameters to get, set and set the fields." I should write private float c_cfr() ??

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to put the word static in front of each method. It is a universal static truth circumference =2pi*r your circle may be bigger than my circle (both instances of circle) but to find the area there is one formula

Answer (score 0):

c_cfr() and c_area() are non static methods which you are trying to call directly from the static main method. Either make the methods c_cfr() and c_area() as static too or access them using object reference.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are trying to acess non static instances and methods of class in static method i.e public static void main(String[] args)

so,change instances and methods to static or create the object of Cerchio and then acess them

```
public class Cerchio {

       static float r;
       float area;
       float cfr;
       
       static  float c_cfr() {
          return (float)(2 * Math.PI* r);
       }

       float c_area() {
          area = (float)(Math.PI * (r*r));
          return area;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args){
          System.out.println("CIRCLE PROGRAM\n");
          Cerchio.r = 5;
       
          Cerchio s = new Cerchior();
          
          System.out.println("The cir is: " +c_cfr());
          System.out.println("The area is: " + s.c_area());
       }
}
```