# Workaround for creating an object to use in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, instance

I have a similar quest like on this topic: [JAVA cannot make a static reference to non-static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482739/java-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-non-static-field)

I understand the problem solving to create an instance of the class an the work with it.
The Problem is, that through the API I'm using, I am not allowed to create a second instance.

Is there a possibility to use the object, that is already created in the `MainActivity`, in my `Fragment`?

I tried already with a getter, but then I get `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method`

Trying to explain the problem more detailed.

In my `MainActivity` I'm creating an object of a APIclass via `object = API.createAPI_Object();` (I'm forced to do it this way cause the API constructor is private)

Because of

```
public static synchronized API createAPI_Object()
  {
    if (numberOfObject == 0)
    {
      numberOfObject++;
    return new API();
  }
    else
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I can only create one instance of the object.

but now I need to use this instance of the object in my `Fragment.class` and I dont know how, because I can't create a new one and I cant use the one of the `MainActivity`(at least I dont know how)

Comment: Paste your code brother???

Comment: hi, do you create your class by newInstance command ? if so, you should put that class into a list. After you can get the existing class and you can do what you want with it.

Comment: ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getInstanceYouWant() and use it in your Fragment

Comment: Hi Fraggles see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I handle Objects from mainActivity in my Fragments:

```
class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

   MyObject mObject;

   onCreate(){
       mObject = new MyObject();
   }       

   public MyObject getMyObject(){
     return mObject;
   }
}



class MyFragment extends Fragment{

   onCreateView(){
       MyObject o = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyObject();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Fraggles the other way would be to create a Manager for those Objects as Singleton, just to give you a little more input

Comment: Maybe another option, but at the moment your method to handle it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking clearly, but my guess is this:

When I normally come across that issue, i set a variable

```
private static Context mContext;
```

and then in my `onCreate()` method (in my fragment) i set `mContext = getActivity()`, and then everytime in a static method, instead of using `getActivity()`, which I can't I use mContext.

If you can post your code and further explain your problem, it will be great.

Comment: I'll try to explain it above in my topic. Because of my company rules I'm not allowed to post all the code :(

Answer (score 0):

Well that is to prevent usage of an object which may not created. If it is created in your FragmentActivity and you don't want to refer it to an object in your fragment, then as description says, you need to make a static reference. You can set your object in your MainFragment static and reach it with the class name like MainActivity.object.