# Initializing a spring bean with command line arguments

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to map command line parameters to an object from the `main` class, and then access them from another class? I have tried with the below, but get an error message: **Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context**. As it's not possible for me to make the methods in `AppConfig` static, what else can I do?

I am trying to initialise a spring bean with command line arguments and this is one way I thought of doing it.

I've just seen I can do what I need for now using a singleton to hold the values before instantiating the beans, and referencing the singleton in the bean. Although this sounds obvious I cannot for the life of me see how to do this with an annotated class. What can I try next?

**Launcher.java**

```
public class Launcher {

   public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
       AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig();
       appConfig.setParam1(args[0]);
       appConfig.setParam2(args[1]); 
       
       AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);
       ...
   }

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
public class AppConfig {
       private String param1;
       private String param2;                

       public String getParam1() {
             return param1;
       }

       public String setParam1(String param1) {
             this.param1 = param1;
       }

       public String getParam2() {
             return param2;
       }

       public String setParam2(String param2) {
             this.param2 = param2;
       }
}
```

**AppContext.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Launcher.class)
@Slf4j
public class AppContext {
       AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig();

       private final String PARAM_1 = appConfig.getParam1();  
       private final String PARAM_2 = appConfig.getParam2();                 
}
```

The alternative for me is to re-instantiate the class again within AppContext, but does that mean I lose access to the command line arguments getting passed through:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Launcher.class)
@Slf4j
public class AppContext {
       

       private final String PARAM_1 = AppConfig.getParam1();  
       private final String PARAM_2 = AppConfig.getParam2();                 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA cannot make a static reference to non-static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482739/java-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-non-static-field)

Comment: Feels like there is some code missing here. For instance `AppContext` should have a `@Configuration` annotation on it. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html for more info

Comment: @jontro I've updated the code

Comment: @TimothyTruckle updated the question with more relevant information to my situation

Comment: There is still the invalid *static access to a non-static method* in `AppConfig.getParam1()`

Comment: Ok I've updated with an alternate approach I was thinking off. Even if I remove the invalid static access, does that still mean I can access the command line arguments from within the spring bean?

Comment: @jontro what are your thoughts... I had a read here but no luck: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/94260-passing-parameters-into-annotationconfigapplicationcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using `private final String PARAM_1 = AppConfig.getParam1();` requires that the method `String getParam1()` MUST be static. Although I do not see it as usual approach.

Comment: I think the question is more related to initializing a spring bean with command line arguments

Comment: Well yes, this is true. The values of `PARAM_1` and `PARAM_2` do not change over time.

Comment: @methuselah, `PARAM_1`, `PARAM_2` never changes over the time, but IMHO these values are unknown before compiling (and I also think b/c of that these values cannot be 'converted' to final values). Or, maybe I'm totally wrong.

Comment: @zlakad what do you recommend? had a look into this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/94260-passing-parameters-into-annotationconfigapplicationcontext but with little success on how to implement it. Can you please help?

Comment: @methuselah -read forum in the link, but honestly, with no experience working with spring, I really don't know how can I help you. All my comments (including this so-called answer) came from my basic knowledge of java. Sorry, friend, and - good luck...