# Getting error while executing a java code

Tags: java

Facing error In this java code.I want to print hello world and var1 value.
Input:

```
import java.util.*; 
class Helloworld{
    Scanner Scannerobj =new Scanner(System.in);
    int var1;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world");
        var1 = Scannerobj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of var1");
   
        System.out.println(var1);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
PS C:\Users\SOUVIK\Desktop>  & 'c:\Users\SOUVIK\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.31.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe' 
'-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages''-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\SOUVIK\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\1fca3cee0a29c97a3fcadb36b4ef44b2\redhat.java\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'Helloworld' 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field var1
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Scannerobj
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field var1
```

Comment: Please show the output of coming your program, and explain what you understand of the error messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA cannot make a static reference to non-static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482739/java-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-non-static-field)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use non static variables from static context as main is static method.So you either make variables static `static Scanner Scannerobj =new Scanner(System.in)`;
`static int var1;`  or define these variables under main function

Answer (score 0):

Define your scanner object and var1 inside main method as below

```
import java.util.*; 
class Helloworld{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int var1;
    Scanner Scannerobj =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("hello world");
    System.out.println("Enter the value of var1");
    var1 = Scannerobj.nextInt();
    System.out.println(var1);
}

}
```

or

Add static keyword while defining scanner object and var1 if you want to define scanner object and var1 outside the main method

```
import java.util.*; 
class Helloworld{
static Scanner Scannerobj =new Scanner(System.in);
static int var1;
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello world");
    System.out.println("Enter the value of var1");
    var1 = Scannerobj.nextInt();
    System.out.println(var1);
}

}
```